# Page numbers of included pdf

Tags: header-footer, pdfpages

Is it possible to display the page numbers of included pdf file? Currently I have the following footer/header definition using fancyhdr

```
%-------------------------------------------------
% Header & Footer
%-------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{{\scriptsize}}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage{}/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

and the following include command using pdfpages

```
\newcommand{\InsertPdfPages}[1]{%
\includepdf[pages={#1},pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}]{./NP2-18.pdf}%
}
```

But I want to have footer looking something like this for pdf included pages

```
\fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage{}(\thepdfincludedpage)/\pageref{LastPage}}}
```

That in the result the footer of included pages looks like this

```
169(23)/423 % <current page>(<number of pdf included page>)/<total number of pages>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example to start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{fancyinsert}{%
  \fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage(\theinsertpage)/\pageref{LastPage}}}%
}

\newcounter{insertpage}
\newcommand{\InsertPdfPages}[1]{%
  \setcounter{insertpage}{0}%
  \includepdf[
    pages={#1},
    pagecommand={%
      \stepcounter{insertpage}%
      \thispagestyle{fancyinsert}%
    },
  ]{NP2-18.pdf}%
}

\begin{document}
  \InsertPdfPages{1-2}
  Last page.
\end{document}
```

It is not very clear, which kind of page number is the "inserted page":

- absolute page number of the inserted PDF document,
- "`\thepage`" number of the inserted PDF document,
- absolute page number of the inserted page range.

The example implements the latter interpretation.

---

The next example provides an example for `\thepage` and more complicate page ranges:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{fancyinsert}{%
  \fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage(\theinsertpage)/\pageref{LastPage}}}%
}

\newcounter{insertpage}
\newcommand{\InsertPdfPages}[1]{%
  \setcounter{insertpage}{0}%
  \includepdf[
    pages={#1},
    pagecommand={%
      \stepcounter{insertpage}%
      \thispagestyle{fancyinsert}%
    },
  ]{NP2-18.pdf}%
}

\begin{document}
  \renewcommand*{\theinsertpage}{%
    \ifcase\value{insertpage}%
      20\or
      21\or
      22\or
      23\or
      24\or
      41\or
      43\or
      44\or
      50\or
      51\or
      52%
    \fi
  }%
  \InsertPdfPages{20-24,41,43,44,50-52}
  Last page.
\end{document}
```

Or a variant that parses the page list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyheadoffset{0mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{fancyinsert}{%
  \fancyfoot[R]{{\scriptsize\thepage(\theinsertpage)/\pageref{LastPage}}}%
}

\newcounter{insertpage}

\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InsertPdfPages}[1]{%
  \comma@parse{#1}{\@InsertPdfPages}%
}
\newcommand*{\@InsertPdfPages}[1]{%
  \@@InsertPdfPages#1-#1-\@nil
}
\def\@@InsertPdfPages#1-#2-#3\@nil{%
  \InsertPdfPageRange{#1}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\InsertPdfPageRange}[2]{%
  \setcounter{insertpage}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{insertpage}{-1}%
  \includepdf[
    pages={#1-#2},
    pagecommand={%
      \stepcounter{insertpage}%
      \thispagestyle{fancyinsert}%
    },
  ]{NP2-18.pdf}%
}

\begin{document}
  \InsertPdfPages{20-24,41,43,44,50-52}
  Last page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I think I did not clarify that. I want to use `\thepage` number of the inserted PDF document.

Comment: Then you can define `\theinsertpage` accordingly and set the correct start value in `\setcounter{insertpage}{...}`.

Comment: I dont think so. What about a range of pages, something like this `page{20,21-24,41,43,44,50-52}`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, if it is not difficult give me last one tip, how to disable  the `(\theinsertpage)` part for not inserted pages?

Comment: @itun Examples fixed by defining a new page style and using `\thispagestyle`.

Comment: You are a kind of Tex guru, I would like to up your answer several more times. Thanks.